# Get Lat Lon out of function in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm wondering how can I get lat and lon out of the function in a variable with global scale in Leaflet. The code to get the coordinates per click in the map works fine but then I can't write my lat and lon in global variables. My code which doesn't work look like this:

```
var lat;
var lon;

function clickEvent(e) {

        if (typeof(newMarker)==='undefined'){
            newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true });
            newMarker.addTo(satMap);}
        else { newMarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);}


        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;
}

satMap.on('click', clickEvent);
document.write(lat);
```

Comment: If code in your app is as in example above it behaves correctly. When statement `document.write(lat);` is executed variable `lat` is undefined since map has not been clicked yet. Whatever you want to do with `lat` and `lon` variables has to be trigerred from inside `clickEvent` or has to happen after the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TomazicM was right, to demo this, your Global is populated but you show undefined because it runs before your click is finished. I modified your code to show you. By putting a function call after Lat, lon is defined by your function you can see it's values are really changed.

```
var lat;
var lon;

function clickEvent(e) {

        if (typeof(newMarker)==='undefined'){
            newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true });
            newMarker.addTo(satMap);}
        else { newMarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);}


        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;
        console.log(lat + " Inside");
        now();
}

satMap.on('click', clickEvent);
console.log(lat + " Global");

function now(){
    console.log(lat + " Global after click");
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it.  I have to call the variables in a function afterwards. Thank you so much for your hints. You saved my Master Thesis :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to attach your function to a click event with `.on('click')`.

For example:

```
var lat;
var lng;

map.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latlng);  //So you can see if it's working
    lat = e.latlng.lat;
    lng = e.latlng.lng;
});
```

There are different ways you can implement the function to include other things (like placing markers), but the main point in your case is the `layer.on('click')` part, otherwise it's not listening for a click. There are some good examples in [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/).

Comment: Unfortunately, if I test it by the document.write (lat); statement out of the function, the variable lat is still undefined.

Comment: If you edit your question to include that part of the script someone might be able to help with that part.

Comment: @user114969 it is `undefined` after you click on the map ?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Answer (score 0):

You just need use `layer.getLatLngs();`
Example :
var coordinates in [this link (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/x4wz9dL5/11/) is your answer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet.draw drawing and editing tools</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@0.4.1/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@0.4.1/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
    <button id="changeColor">Rectangle -> Blue</button>
    <script>
        var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib}),
            map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(51.509, -0.08), zoom: 14 });

        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(drawnItems);

        var polyLayers = [];

        var polygon1 = L.polygon([
            [51.509, -0.08],
            [51.503, -0.06],
            [51.51, -0.047]
        ]);
        polyLayers.push(polygon1)

        var polygon2 = L.polygon([
            [51.512642, -0.099993],
            [51.520387, -0.087633],
            [51.509116, -0.082483]
        ]);
        polyLayers.push(polygon2)

        // Add the layers to the drawnItems feature group 
        for(layer of polyLayers) {
            drawnItems.addLayer(layer); 
        }


        // Set the title to show on the polygon button
        L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw a   polygon!';

        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            position: 'topright',
            draw: {



                marker: false
            },
            edit: {
                featureGroup: drawnItems,
                remove: false
            }
        });
        map.addControl(drawControl);

        map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;

            if (type === 'marker') {
                layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
            }

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
      var cordinates =        layer.getLatLngs();

      console.log(cordinates);
        });

        map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
            var layers = e.layers;
            var countOfEditedLayers = 0;
            layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                countOfEditedLayers++;
            });
            console.log("Edited " + countOfEditedLayers + " layers");
        });



        L.DomUtil.get('changeColor').onclick = function () {
            drawControl.setDrawingOptions({ rectangle: { shapeOptions: { color: '#004a80' } } });
        };




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```